# Multiple build operations failed. Android error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
 plugins {
            id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
            id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
            id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
            id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.16" apply false
        }
    
    
    
        compileOptions {
            isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        }
    
    
    dependencies {
    
        coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4")
    
    
    }
```

when changing from

```
 id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
```

to

```
 id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
```

it throws the the error

> Multiple build operations failed.
> coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please    add dependencies
> to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
> coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please    add dependencies
> to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration. coreLibraryDesugaring
> configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core
> library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring
> configuration.

Comment: Did you try with `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` and not `17` in `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` ?

Comment: but the latest Android studio warns to use VERSION_1_8  by saying to use VERSION_17

Answer (score 0):

1st of fall you can try with `Invalidate Caches` like the below Image

[image]

Then you can open `terminal` and try this command `.\gradlew clean`

```
.\gradlew clean
```

I do the same thing my same problem is to solve

### Edit

This problem is with the Gradle plugin `8.6-rc-2` `8.4.0-alpha05` you can change the Gradle plugin in `gradle-wrapper.properties` **distributionUrl** like below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: Multiple build operations failed.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
    coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.
coreLibraryDesugaring configuration contains no dependencies. If you intend to enable core library desugaring, please add dependencies to coreLibraryDesugaring configuration.



still get this error

Comment: can you add this `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true` in `defaultConfig`

Comment: have already added that in gradel file

Comment: i am using kotlin ksp instead of kapt might be the issue related ksp plugin